# HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request

Tags: php, web

I am new in PHP and I am making a script. Can you help, where am I wrong?
I would also like to understand it not only have the code because I am learning. It is an IP ban script (Or i want it to be :D )

```
<?php
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'mypasss') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db('databse')
$ip = (isset($_SERVER)) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
echo "Your IP: ".$ip; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `user` WHERE `ip` = '$ip'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') 
            === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';

$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;


if ($row) {

   header("Location: $currentUrl/ban/ban.php"); 
   exit(); 
} else {
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT  INTO user(ip) VALUES ('".$ip."') ");
 header("Location: $currentUrl/ban/ban.php");
}

?>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please be specific about the error that you might be getting.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly "is wrong" and give a proper explanation and title?

Comment: It just does not load. You can get it here http://malamut.hu/prog/bottracker/caught_bot/

Comment: **You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code** ([why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)), they are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Use [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead

Comment: but I use mysql_connect in other projects, and those are working well.

Comment: So, you want to insert IP in the ban table, if the user is not already banned? Does it happen, no matter the blank page? Also you are checking if $row is true for some reason, should you extract the result and then check it?

Comment: Yes. I wan to insert there if it is not banned. It is a bot tracker and it will be in a denied folder by robots.txt.. If the ip is there, I don't want to write in the database. that is $row

Comment: And I can also tell that it will be a bot banner script for me and some friends because I hate 3000 visitors on my site which is not really that big: http://malamut.hu

Comment: @MLL They're working well for now, but the MySQL extension is no longer maintained and will eventually go away entirely.

Comment: okey, but I am not on that level to think of future. I would like to learn today :D if the script is wrking, then I will correct that

Comment: Okey guys, Thank you for help, The problem was very simple.
I found it and it is on line 3. THe semicolon is missing
Thanks for everyon's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error_reporting is off and therefore you get no error like "Cannot modify header information – headers already sent" because you make an `echo "Your IP: ".$ip;` before the `header()`-call and this usually will cause an error. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understanded what is the problem here. I also looked up the link you showed

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very beginning in your script and comment the `echo` out, reload site, if there is an error, pls report

Comment: Okay, I found the problem it was the missing semicolon after 
   mysql_select_db('database');

Comment: so it seems that error_reporting is off at your server? maybe you should enable it via .htaccess while developing, helps a lot to find these kind of errors

Comment: I don't know. I will look after it

Comment: Do you know some good free SQL hosts? Because mine only listens to the calls from their own server